# Can't break out of for(each) loop java

Tags: java, for-loop, file-io

I am new here, as you can see this is my first post. I'm writing a program that reads in user input of a file and then proceeds to search the computer (provided a user directory) for that file and then prints out the exact directory where the file was found.

The problem is, this method will find the directory but then runs infinitely, and I can't seem to break out of it. Maybe I'm missing something but I thought I covered every case so that when it does find the full directory it stops running the method. Here's the code:

```
public void findFile(File d, String fileName, boolean found) {
    File[] newArray = d.listFiles();
    for (File z : newArray) {
        if (fileName.equals(z.getName())) {
            System.out.println("The location of the file is: " + z.getParentFile());
            break;
        }
        else if(!found){
            if(z.isDirectory() && z.getName().charAt(0) != '.') {
                findFile(z, fileName, found);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's where the method is called (case 3):

```
switch (answer) {
        case 1:
            directory(false);
            break;
        case 2:
            directory(true);
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Enter the file you would like to locate:");
            String newFile = keyboard.nextLine();
            findFile(new File("/Users/Josh"), newFile, false);
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("Program ended.");
            condition = false;
            break;
        }
```

The program will run infinitely through the "else if" statement of the "findFile" method after it finds the directory of the file that I'm looking for.
Sorry if this is a bad post or too long, I'm new. Thanks.

Comment: Your `findFile` method should return a value to which the caller can decide if it should continue process or not

Comment: you are not setting `found` variable in method. and why you are checking file if you are not taking output as it got found or not ??

Comment: If  'boolean found' means whether the file is found, then you have a bad naming convention!  Here is some suggestion about how to make naming more meaningful.  'boolean found' --> 'boolean isFileFound'  'File[] newArray' --> 'File[] files'  'File z : newArray' --> 'File file : files'

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite like so

```
public boolean findFile(File d, String fileName) {
    boolean found = false;
    File[] newArray = d.listFiles();
    for (File z : newArray) {
        if (fileName.equals(z.getName())) {
            System.out.println("The location of the file is: " + z.getParentFile());
            found = true;
        } else {
            if (z.isDirectory() && z.getName().charAt(0) != '.') {
                found = findFile(z, fileName);
            }
        }
        if(found){
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you find the file, your recursion doesn't stop. The parameter `found` is not of much use in your method. I would suggest something like this (haven't tested, but should make clear what I mean):

```
public boolean findFile(File d, String fileName) {
    // check if file exists in current directory
    if (new File(d, filename).exists() {
        System.out.println("The location of the file is: " + d);
        return true;
    }

    // if not, look in subdirectories
    for (File f: d.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isDirectory() && findFile(f, fileName)) {
            // findFile returned true, so it was found
            return true;
        }
    }

    // not found
    return false;
}
```

If you want to find all files with the name (there could be more than one in different subdirs), you can set the return type to `void` and remove the return statements.

You could also use [Files.walkFileTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor)).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use an approach like this where with some modify to the method signature and to the return statement you will solve your problem really fast!

```
public File[] finder(String dirName){   
    File dir = new File(dirName);
    return dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {      
       public boolean accept(File dir, String filename)      { 
          return filename.endsWith(".txt"); 
       }    
    }); 
}
```